# vocalizations meaning for rats/mice

Tags: mouse

Rats (rattus norvegicus) vocalizations are said (in the literature) to have some positive or negative meaning, mostly 22kHz vs 50 to 80kHz. Some papers hints to nearly syllables, describing a number of different class of vocalizations depending on their spectrogram shapes.

Could we give any meaning to those "syllables" ? Couldnt find any specific answer.

Comment: What did you find during your research?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that *show* little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site — saying you couldn't find an answer is not sufficient. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: When searching, also try the term “DeepSqueak”. This delightfully named software is for analysing ultrasonic vocalisations.

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments. The thing is I have done a few year of academic research on the subject and where I state 'couldn't find any specific answer' I mean papers are only describing the USV but usually don't go as far as giving any meaning nor studying their occurrence in time mostly they correlate pitch with positive or negative behaviours / environement such as stress, eating ... and mostly with very young individuals